# box2d prismatic joint friction

Tags: box2d, joints

I know it is possible to add friction to rev joints by enabling motor and adding `maxMotorTorque`. I want the same for prism joint but only `maxMotorSpeed` option is available which didn't quite work for me. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [`SetMaxMotorForce`](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/848b8fddf348ae0090f0046c845e1170c1331a1b/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2PrismaticJoint.h). This function is analogous to `SetMaxMotorTorque` for `b2RevoluteJoint`s.

Comment: You are right, it should be called _force_ instead of _torque_ as it is not rotating. So that is the correct terminology.